# Left the Netherlands in Aug '14, saw “Terug te krijgen" on tax file, tax refunds?

Tags: taxes, netherlands, salary

Was on the 30% ruling before I left the Netherlands in Aug 2014.  Just looked at my tax file for 2014, and there was an amount of euro 1k+ listed as “Terug te krijgen.”  Does it mean that I will receive money from the tax office automatically?

I never filed tax refund.  As I understood, taxes were deducted from my monthly income.  The HR office refused to help.

Comment: What tax file is that? The [mijn.belastingdienst.nl](https://mijn.belastingdienst.nl/mbd-pmb/) website?

Comment: Did you work elsewhere after August 2014? That might change the rules and/or prevent you from using the app.

Comment: Yes, the mijn.belastingdienst.nl  website.  There's a 2014 tax file that I can get access to.  I can sign, but cannot send it, no matter how many times I tried.

Comment: I did not work after Aug 2014.

Comment: That's what you are supposed to do to file a tax return, nothing more. Until now, I have used the app rather than the website, so I don't know exactly how it works but it sounds like a technical glitch. What do you see when you try to send/confirm it?

Comment: More info: I deregistered in Aug 2014. Then I saw that my residence status is “verblijft onrechtmatig in Nederland” and I still have an estimated income for 2015 on my Toeslagen. At the same time, I logged on my tax, and saw the “Terug te krijgen" on tax file. I mailed to the tax office to inform them that I left the NL and asked for the tax refunds. I now see that they've removed the "verblijft onrechtmatig" status on my Toeslagen, but did not answer my tax refund inquiry.

Comment: The system indicated that I signed it on a certain date (I did go through the form), but when I tried to send it, it said "there is some technical error."  I've been trying it on a quite regular basis for 3 months now, the same error is still there.

Comment: I don't know what's happening or how to file a tax return in your situation but as I wrote in my answer, I don't think you will get any money before you do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tax rates are progressive, the higher your income over the whole year, the higher the tax percentage. The amounts that were deducted from your monthly income are always based on the assumption that you would receive that income for the entire year.

If you only worked for 8 months, your total yearly income will be lower than assumed, and less of it will be in the highest percentage range.

So it is normal that if you only work part of the year, you will get part of your deducted tax returned. But you need to file.

Answer (score 1):

It's a few years that filing a tax return has not involved filling a lot of forms in the Netherlands, at least in the most common situations. Your employer does indeed withhold income tax from your salary and provide a lot of information to the tax office (banks do too, incidentally). The tax office then uses that information to pre-fill your tax return and, unless you have some other income or special deductions, you merely have to confirm it is correct to officially file a tax return.

If you have an account on the [mijn.belastingdienst.nl](https://mijn.belastingdienst.nl/mbd-pmb/) website, you can do it there. Before that, there was an app, which is still available. If you used either of those, you might in fact already have filed a tax return.

Beyond that, it does sound like you might get a refund – which is not unusual given the way the system works, especially if you stopped working during the year – but I never actually got any money without formally filing a tax return, even if that's as simple as clicking through the app and “signing” it with my DigiD.

What did happen to me once is that I got a letter along the lines of “You should be eligible for a tax refund for the year XXXX, please submit a tax return to get it", which did work perfectly. In any case, in the Netherlands, you have several years to do that so nothing is lost at this point.